# Could you use radio waves to hide communications in a tech advanced, future setting?

Tags: technology, communication

You're on a space station, and it uses all the hi-tech communications we're used to today - the best wifi/local networks, as well as something I call hypercom (hand waving), using hyperspace to send messages.

Hero wants a way to communicate with a resistance force that bad guy won't detect - he is listening to all the normal channels.

Would building a basic 2-way radio work? Would there be a specific wavelength that could be used to this effect? The idea is to sneak in with a low-tech idea the bad guy won't hear.

The distance needed for such communication would need to be around 4-500 meters,

Comment: What kind of messages does the hero want to send? A one-way coded message like "attack at dawn" would be easier and less noticeable than two-way voice, for instance.

Comment: Also, are the hero and the resistance force both on the station, or are they communicating from the station to somewhere else?

Comment: Well, if the opponent is "listening to all the normal channels", all the hero has to do is communicate on an **ab**normal channel. Read about [spread spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_spectrum) techniques, which (among other desirable qualities) have the property the for a receiver who is not privy to the keying method the signal is indistinguishable from noise, and even the presence or absence of a signal is quite hard to detect. Now, of course, the problem is that the question does not indicate over what distance the hero wants to communicate, which is very important.

Comment: @Cadence Same station

Comment: @AlexP I will look at that, hopefully, it's not above my head. Let's say the distance is like a kilometer at most.

Comment: And, importantly, on a space station - what is the intervening material?  There are some frequencies that travel very well through solids, and some that do not.  Is it a big open space inside the station, or are there lots and lots and lots of metal walls between point A and point B?

Comment: Please [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/240310/edit) the question and add this piece of data. (And try to decrease that maximum distance. What is a nice little signal at one kilometer distance is a big whopping lighthouse at one meter from the emitter.) (And anyway, the question states that the station has Wi-Fi or similar. This means that there is a data communications network. Which means that the hero can use the station's own network to communicate surreptitiously using a variety of methods.)

Comment: (Also, it's worth noting overall that wifi and similar communications _are_ using radio waves.  So if the bad guy can use wifi, he has plenty of radio receivers.  This is the same reason that, in Independence Day, it's silly that the aliens couldn't intercept Morse Code when they'd already broken inter-satellite encryption.)

Comment: @AlexP Edited, let's say 4-500 meters. You said "the hero can use the station's own network to communicate surreptitiously using a variety of methods" - can you elaborate or provide some reading for me? This is not at all something I know much about. :/

Comment: @jdunlop Lots of interference and not much open space. Lots of walls, metal, wiring, plumbing, etc.

Comment: As a starting point, I might recommend looking up _steganography_.  Rather than obvious, suspicious, encrypted communications, our hero posts a funny cat picture on the station message board.

Comment: @jdunlop I'll look into that as an option thanks - would this actually work with printed images?

Comment: The problem with printing and scanning images, steganographically speaking, is that you won't get a pixel-perfect recreation at the end because of the mechanical limitations of the printer and scanner. Even a slight imperfection will essentially randomize the highest-precision data bits that you're using to carry your message.

Comment: @Cadence - I mean, yes, but this could be avoided by making the encoded data less pixel-precise, at the risk of making it more obvious to the naked eye.  But I didn't mean a corkboard, MajorTom, I meant on the public network.

Comment: @jdunlop So if I understand in very general terms - I post an image on some public network (let's say a job board) with the encoding. My guy who needs to read it looks at that image and decodes it to get the message. Correct?

Comment: Yep!  For instance, use this: https://i.ibb.co/g6s5hJn/innocent-kittens-and-not-a-secret-message.png as an input to the "Decode" tab here: https://stylesuxx.github.io/steganography/

Comment: @jdunlop Thanks for this, I think this is the approach I am going to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The idea is to sneak in with a low-tech idea the bad guy won't hear.

Generally, the more sophisticated a modulation/encoding, the less power it uses and the more it looks like background noise. Something "low tech" like a continuous carrier amplitude-modulated with analog audio will stick out like a sore thumb to any instrument monitoring the local radio activity.

Rather than a low-tech radio, consider relatively high-tech methods like the steganography mentioned by some others, code words or symbols left in public communications, or prearranged signals sent via means that aren't usually considered communication, like turning particular lights on or off at particular times. Your bit rate is likely to be rather poor, of course, and attempts to send large amounts of data are likely to attract notice.

If only one of them is being monitored, it may not be suspicious for them both to regularly visit the same location...both could favor having lunch at the same restaurant, for example. Once they are both in the same location, they could exchange information by a variety of ways that might be overlooked by careless observers, for example by [tap codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code) or surreptitious sign language. This would allow a two-way conversation (albeit a slow and simplified one), and allow for variations of [dead drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_drop) techniques for exchanging objects encoding more detailed information.

Comment: That makes sense. The trick here, they need to have a "normal" conversation if possible.

Comment: @MajorTom Does it have to be a verbal conversation, or would a text exchange work? Are you trying to disguise the fact that these two people are conversing, or just the content of their conversation? How often and for how long do you need to do this? Some obsolete comms gear might suffice for a one-time thing...even if they immediately notice that someone's talking to someone else, it may all be over by the time they can decode it or dig out the equipment to track the sources down.

Comment: Trying to not let the bad guy know they are talking. The one guy is being monitored. So both the fact that they are talking AND the content must be hidden. They have to talk daily. COULD be a text exchange, but that seems to be a different flavor of the same problem.

Comment: Chose this because it also mentioned steganography which I am using, first mentioned by @jdunlop.

Answer (score 2):

Use ultrasound carried through the space station's structure: the high-tech version of tapping morse on the radiator.

For security, keep messages short. Only transmit at certain times. Make the bursts resemble the sort of sounds the space station makes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Doubtful.** At least not without some sort of trick.

You can't really even do this today. There are numerous techniques to thwart *understanding* of a message, but the options to *avoid detection of a transmission at all* are already limited, and I would expect that as time goes by, broadband reception will become easier while "sneaky transmission" doesn't improve at all.

For example, you can, today, broadcast a frequency hopping message that is, additionally, encrypted. Only someone with the decryption key and the hopping algorithm can read the message, but anyone with a sufficiently broad spectrum receiver (or array of receivers, or fast scanner, or array of fast scanners) can definitely pick up the entire transmission (and pinpoint its location).

One possibility, if you know where the enemy receiver is at, is to jam him. You place some sort of jammer near his receiver set to activate when the time is right. The jammer can be very weak as long as it's very near his receiver and not near the intended rebel receiver. The enemy can't hear your transmission because it's lost in the jamming, but to the intended rebel receiver, your transmission overpowers the jammer, since he's further away from it.

The bad guy will know something is up, but not what, or where. He'll have to find that jammer and shut it down first.

Another option might be to have a transmitter wired (via a lengthy physical connection) to the microphone. Or set the transmitter to transmit a recording. In this case, the bad guy can hear the transmission, and know where the transmitter is, but at least the hero's actual physical location is not immediately found out.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, due to [power line noise.](https://www.arrl.org/power-line-noise)

The station has very old and very expensive to replace power lines with lots of small faults and problems, which causes a lot of radio noise in certain spectrums. While an advanced sci fi station would of course monitor all radio communication, there's enough static on this channel that they can't clearly detect signals and fresh parts and maintenance crew to fix it are pretty low down on their supporter's priority lists.

The bad guys have turned off notifications from their computers about any signals in this area that aren't overt, because there's just so many random noises.

The protagonist has a way to trigger a power line failure which sends a fixed radio signal noise. They can then use their radio and a simple computer device to filter out the predictable noise and talk to their companion.

The bad guy's computers will detect the radio noise, but because it's masked by the electronic noise won't flag it up, or if they do flag it up, it'll probably be ignored as another maintenance glitch that they don't have the time or money to fix.

## The resistance may be helping with the bad maintenance

They don't want the bad guy to have a fully functional space station that can detect them and their ongoing deeds, so they may intentionally sabotage parts of the station to give themselves more leeway.

## You need one time codes for this

Spaceships are gonna have advanced computers scanning everything for communication and frequencies and encryption because that's easy and cheap to do today, so why not do it on an advanced sci fi station?

As such to fix it, when he and the resistance meet, they need to exchange a set of power line noises to use to communicate. It's easy to hide such on a jailbroken electronic device. This will generate random and unpredictable radio noise around the power line that you can compensate for, but they cannot. Once you've set up the codes you can communicate freely with only rare face to face meetings needed.

Comment: Not mentioned in the question - the baddie is an AI with a whole network of sub-AIs. He can monitor everything and it is not a problem - and he is.

Comment: Then presumably he's told whatever sub AI monitors radio transmissions to ignore power conduit noise, because they want to focus on important business rather than the many false alarms the power conduits give.

Answer (score 1):

**Yell.**

Your baddy is probably not on the station.  Or the goodies would find his pants and cut the crotches out.  Unless it turns out baddy had already cut them out himself!

Where was I?  Yes - on the station.  Baddy is monitoring radio.  You could yell to your buds on the other side of the station.  If your throat was hoarse from yelling you could get a megaphone or a microphone and a 6 foot stack of amps and communicate that way.  Woops - this is a metric question.  2 meter stack of amps.

Physics stack says a shout can travel a couple of km.  More than you need.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415409/how-far-can-a-shout-travel

Or since you have the amps set up you could communicate in code with various guitar riffs corresponding to words and phrases.  Actually bass guitar would be better since low tones travel farther.  The drums would be very tom heavy.  If that has been done I have not seen it.  Or heard it.  I can picture the exchange - the rebel bassist listening intently, nodding as she understands, then tearing into her bass for her reply.  The drummer picks up a second later; he does not understand bassspeak but does understand groovy.

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is to sneak in with a low-tech idea the bad guy won't hear.

> The distance needed for such communication would need to be around 4-500 meters,

Train a rat or similar animal to carry a note or usb drive around. This is as low tech as you can get while still being stealthy. This is also completely radio silent.

If you do want to use electromagnetic radiation: use a wire. An electric signal going through a wire is EM going through it, analogue to light bouncing within optical fiber. If you pass the wire yourself through wherever, it's unlikely the villain will be able to tap it.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly - there was the famous US Wargames where an Old-school general 'sunk' a US Carrier, using signal flags and motorbike runners to communicate.

And this is something that Western Militaries, especially in the wake of fighting insurgency/asymmetric warfare scenarios have been particularly concerned with.

So, it's possible. In your scenario - the impediment is that such an opposition would likely have the ability to detect radio waves (as they are part of the Electromagnetic Spectrum - and any space fairing entity would need to monitor the EM band).

However - even if they detect it, whether they have the ability to listen to it or recognize that it is a communications channel is another thing.

You could have your hero teach the resistance Morse Code (or future Sci-Fi equivalent) and use radio 'bursts' for the dots and dashes - which could much more easily pass for 'static' and 'interference' (being intermittent in nature) Also potential plot points for someone on the bad side convinced that it's not natural interference as it's not random...

Comment: In reality, a Morse code burst does not look *at all* like noise, while, on the other hand, modern Bluetooth and Wi-Fi signals are *designed* to look like noise. (Not for the purpose of hiding them, but because if the signal looks like noise you can cram more independent signals in a given bandwidth, because for receivers who are not a party to the conversation they *are* noise.)

Comment: Looks like OP updated the question from when I posted my answer. When I meant noise - I didn't mean in the technical sense, more in the sense of 'something believed to be so inconsequential as to be ignored' - as in "What's that?" "That? Oh that's nothing. Probably just a loose connection somewhere"

Comment: In reality the monitoring is done by automated machinery, for which the only kind of noise that is treated as ignorable noise is actual noise in the technical sense. Everything is which not noise in the technical sense is a signal, which is then automatically compared with a list of known signals; and if it cannot be classified as a known allowed signal it is passed to the higher layers for investigation.

Comment: Heh - so I work in IT and have spent decades fine-tuning Monitoring systems - There is a lot of scenarios where intermittent issues don't generate Alarms and duration is definitely a big factor - e.g. if a fault state exists for less than X amount of time, then no alarm is triggered. A Quick burst could easily slip by a monitoring system as 'not significant enough to warrant investigation'

Answer (score -1):

Can the space station see the rebel base on the surface? If they can, then a light beam might be the easiest way to communicate. A laser beam would be very collimated, so someone would have to be at the actual site to pick it up. Make it near-IR so it will not be seen by accident, but it can still be focussed by conventional glass optics. The ground receiver could be a small telescope with a silicon detector and a bandpass filter, plus a laser to return a signal. With a bit of cunning the laser and detector could be made to work as some other device, such as a laser rangefinder, so the ground-based unit would look innocent when dismantled.

You can get a huge amount of data onto a light beam, but straight AM would be easy to do and would be enough to send a voice signal.

The space station might have to have a more complicated detector to pick up a signal if the rebels move about, but they can have a larger telescope and a larger detector without having to look innocent.

Postscript:

I had missed the distance, or maybe I read it as being in Km rather than m. Apologies. So, they are both on the same space station or some craft nearby.

Near-IR could still work. You don't have to point it accurately for those ranges. You can use diffuse reflections to send it around corners.

Sending ultrasound through the structure could work if you were on the same structure.

In either case, avoid making transmissions look like Morse code, or any kind of obvious conversation. Keep messages as brief as possible. Make the messages look like the background noise. A small burst of IR might be a reflection of a star or something. But if you know to look for a short burst of 950 nm light at 13m 27s past each hour, it becomes much easier to separate from the background.

Comment: From the range expressed by the OP (400m-1km), I doubt very much that the resistance force is on the surface; I think they're on board the station as well.  If there's too much intervening material to allow for easy radio transmission, line-of-sight transmission isn't going to work.

Comment: True. I had missed that somehow. They could communicate via the ground, but the becomes much less attractive. However, they could aim their IR out of the window, and bounce it off some other part of the station that the other side can see. Or use diffuse reflections and scatter within the space station.

Comment: They are together on a space station.

Comment: Added postscript to correct for this. Thanks.